# Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a python script to run everyday for backing up the configurations from network devices-Palo Alto Firewalls. I'm using the API functionality for logging into the devices. Since some of the characters are not decoded, I'm getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So, here's the part of the code which is throwing the error:

```
r = requests.get('https://%s/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=password' %host, verify=False)
```

The password contains special characters like '+', '@'. I've checked the kb article for Paloalto and they have a solution when we manually enter the HTTPS URL: (https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000CliMCAS).

They suggested:

> For instance, if the password contains special characters such as "#"
>   and "&," use the URL encode %23 and %26 respectively.

This works when I manually enter the password. But while passing the arguments in the get request, how do I pass it for the decoded values of say, '+' (decoded value is %2B)?

So say password is p@ssword+, the one we enter in the code for get request api url will be https://192.168.10.1/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=p%40ssword%2B

This will give:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 0):

> So say password is p@ssword+, the one we enter in the code for get
>   request api url will be
>   https://192.168.10.1/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=p%40ssword%2B

If you directly use that as argument for the `get` function, the `%40s` and `%2B` will be treated as [string formatting specifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

> The `'%'` character, which marks the start of the specifier.

You have to escape the `%` character with another `%`:

> `'%'`  No argument is converted, results in a '%' character in the
>   result.

Try this:

```
url_fmt = "https://%s/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=p%%40ssword%%2B"
host = "api"
print(url_fmt % host)

# https://api/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=p%40ssword%2B
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.format` function.

```
"https://{}/api/?type=keygen&user=admin&password=password".format(host)
```